# 404 error for static assets when browser caching implemented on nginx

Tags: nginx, cache

I have an nginx.conf file currently that looks like this (with brackets replacing sensitive data):

```
worker_processes  3;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    access_log  [/...];
    error_log   [/...]  crit;

    include mime.types;
    sendfile on;

    server {
        server_name [...] [...];
        return 301 [...] $request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:[...];
        root [/...];

        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass [.../uwsgi.sock];
        }
    }
}
```

If I add the following line after the existing location {...} clause, as suggested [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/leverage-browser-caching-for-nginx), loading the website will produce "404 not found" errors for image, CSS, and js assets:

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 1d;
}
```

How can I implement browser caching, without causing the "404" issue?

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple issue of your location statements being out of order.

Your wrote that you put the static file location clause *after* the `location / {}` block. This means your static files will be checked for there, first. Since your uwsgi socket can't find the file paths, it returns 404.

What you want will look more like this.

```
http {
    [..]

    server {
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 ^ $request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen localhost;
        root /path/to/webroot/;

        location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
            expires 1d;
        }
        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass [...];
        }
    }
}
```

The good people at Digital Ocean have [an excellent guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms#matching-location-blocks) explaining how this works. I recommend reading it through.

Comment: I had tried your recommendation, and it seemed to be working, so I marked the answer as correct. A few minutes later, I tried visiting the site again, and I'm getting the same 404 error. Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: @Boa then it sounds like it's more likely an issue with your uwsgi implementation. Without knowing more about your setup, I can't really say.

Comment: Thanks. Can you offer any advice on what to look for, or on what sort of additional data I should post that could be useful to diagnosing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

[The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42998387/4400277) that resolved my issue was to put the `uwsgi_pass [.../uwsgi.sock];` clause inside of each `location {...}` block.

Comment: Sure. Do you know why?